# HTML5 Canvas and bubble.js

Tags: javascript, wordpress, html

I am trying to add an HTML5 **canvas** and in the canvas I want to animate some texts. I'm using `alphabet.js`, `bubble.js`, and a custom script. Trying to add the canvas in my header.

All my scripts and canvas are loaded properly but the following script is not working:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var red = [0, 100, 63];
    var blue = [196, 77, 55];
    var green = [75, 100, 40];
    var orange = [40, 77, 55];
    var purple = [280, 50, 60];
    alert("Hello!");
    var myName = "Welcome to";
    var letterColors = [blue, red, orange, green, purple];
    if ( 15 > 5 ) {
        bubbleShape = "circle";
    } else {
        bubbleShape = "square";
    }
    drawName(myName, letterColors);
    bounceBubbles();
});
```

If I put an alert message in the script, it works if I place it before `drawName(myName, letterColors)`.

Comment: You need to look at how to properly build an array (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

You need to ensure your array values have a quotation mark around them.

Answer (score 0):

This may fix your problem, assuming there is nothing else going on. It's a simple issue of quotation marks around your array values:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var red = [0, 100, 63];
    var blue = [196, 77, 55];
    var green = [75, 100, 40];
    var orange = [40, 77, 55];
    var purple = [280, 50, 60];
    alert("Hello!");
    var myName = "Welcome to";
    var letterColors = ['blue', 'red', 'orange', 'green', 'purple'];
    if ( 15 > 5 ) {
        bubbleShape = "circle";
    } else {
        bubbleShape = "square";
    }
    drawName(myName, letterColors);
    bounceBubbles();
});
```

Failing this, give the javascript console a look to see any additional errors.

Comment: Thanks Adam A. Tried this and still got the error in the console: drawName is not defined

Comment: Do you have "bubble.js" included in either the head or before the closing "</body>" tag?